# The script on the page to access the variable Google Chrome plug-in?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Tell me, please, can the script on the page to access the variable Chrome extension?
I have written an extension for Google Chrome and do not want the owner of the site on which to run the extension could read the contents of the variables in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

No, regular scripts can't access Chrome extensions or any variables defined in them.